# Capybara can't click on button

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, capybara

Im new to capybara and poltergeist, but here's what I have so far.

It finds the button but fails to click on it. I've tried 'execute_script' but i cant get that to work either due to a NotSupportedByDriverError. I've included gem 'capybara-webkit' but that didn't change anything.

Line in question:

```
assert page.execute_script("$('.js-login-action').click()"), "Failed to click on Login"
```

Here's the full test.rb file

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

options = {js_errors: false, js: true}
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end

 class LoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "Load login page" do
    visit("/users/sign_in")
    assert page.has_content?('derp'), "Page does not have Derp heading"
  end

  test "Successful load of sign in page" do
    get("/users/sign_in")
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "Login" do
    visit("/users/sign_in")
    fill_in "login-username", with: 'derp'
    fill_in "login-password", with: '0123456789'
    assert find_button("Login"), "Failed to Find Login Button"
    assert page.execute_script("$('.js-login-action').click()"), "Failed to click on Login"
    assert page.has_css?('en-main-header'), "Failed to Login"

  end

end
```

Comment: what is the button you want to click on? can you share his html code? (for example `<input tabindex="0" type="submit" value="Save Edits">`)

Answer (score 2):

The `page.execute_script` is not really meant to click on a button.
As you can see in this very helpful [capybara cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105), you can click on a button in different ways. For example:

```
click_button('Save')
```

or

```
find_button('Send').click
```

or

```
find('//table/tr').click
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things going wrong here:

1. You're setting up your javascript driver but then not telling your tests to use the javascript driver, so instead they are using the default driver which is rack-test and doesn't support javascript at all (hence the unsupported by driver error)  You can either set Capybara.default_driver to :poltergeist if you want all tests to run with JS support, or look into setting the driver via metadata with something like https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-capybara
2. As @fabersky points out, you should be using click_button or Node#click to click on items in the page  So - `click_button('Login')` - which removes the need for you assertion on find_button since click_button will error if it can't find the button.
3. Asserting on find_button doesn't read very well, you'd be better off using something like `page.assert_selector :button, 'Login'` which will provide a more descriptive error message on failure.  Same goes for your assert has_css? which could be `page.assert_selector(:css, 'en-main-header')` - the :css is optional if your default selector is set to :css - which would give a more descriptive error about what was looked for/missing
4. Asserting on the result of execute_script is not going to work since by definition execute_script doesn't return anything.  If you really want to check the result of some JS being executed on the page you want to use evaluate_script